# React-Redux does not re-render component with two back-to-back actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which listens to a certain value in the Redux store with a `useSelector`. It should re-render *whenever* that value changes. Though, when I'm dispatching two actions immediately after each other, it skips the first value change and does not re-render the component.

I can fix the issue by wrapping both dispatch calls inside a single `setTimout(…, 0)`. But this is probably a dirty workaround, and I would like to know what is responsible for this mismatch with my expectations in the first place.

A minimal example can be found in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/lenzls/pen/GRMYJMz?editors=1011

#### Excerpts

```
function StatusDisplay () {
  const comparisonFunc = (newSelectedState, latestSelectedState) => {
    const equality = newSelectedState === latestSelectedState
    console.log(`[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: ${newSelectedState} | old: ${latestSelectedState} | equal?: ${equality}`)
    return equality
  }

  const status = useSelector(state => state.status, comparisonFunc)

  console.log(`[StatusDisplay] — !!render component — status: ${status}`)
  
  return <div>UpdatTestComp {status}</div>
}
```

```
function App () {
  const changeState = () => {
    console.warn(`PRESSING BUTTON`)
    console.log(`Dispatch status = empty — Expecting [StatusDisplay] to rerender…`)
    store.dispatch({type: 'CHANGE', payload: 'empty'});
    console.log(`Dispatch status = error — Expecting [StatusDisplay] to rerender…`)
    store.dispatch({type: 'CHANGE', payload: 'error'});
  }
  
  const changeStateAfterTimeout = () => setTimeout(changeState, 0)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeState}>dispatch two actions</button>
      <button onClick={changeStateAfterTimeout}>dispatch two actions after timeout</button>
      <StatusDisplay />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Example

On page load, the initial status is `error`. Console prints

```
"Initial status: error"
"[StatusDisplay] — !!render component — status: error"
```

Then I press the `dispatch two actions` button. Console prints

```
"PRESSING BUTTON"
"Dispatch status = empty — Expecting [StatusDisplay] to rerender…"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: empty | old: error | equal?: false"
"Dispatch status = error — Expecting [StatusDisplay] to rerender…"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: error | old: empty | equal?: false"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: error | old: error | equal?: true"
"[StatusDisplay] — !!render component — status: error"
```

We see that the comparison function of the `useSelector` is actually called immediately after the state change (and before the second action), but the component still does not re-render.

If I press the `dispatch two actions after timeout` button, console prints

```
"PRESSING BUTTON"
"Dispatch status = empty — Expecting [StatusDisplay] to rerender…"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: empty | old: error | equal?: false"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: empty | old: empty | equal?: true"
"[StatusDisplay] — !!render component — status: empty"
"Dispatch status = error — Expecting [StatusDisplay] to rerender…"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: error | old: empty | equal?: false"
"[StatusDisplay] — Call comparisonFunc — new: error | old: error | equal?: true"
"[StatusDisplay] — !!render component — status: error"
```

In this case, the component actually renders twice, once for each change of `status`. This is what I would expect to happen in either case.

---

I assume that Redux' `dispatch` is actually synchronous as described [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-store-update-events), but there is some optimization in react-redux going on. I can't find information about it in the docs though.

In general, my actual example is a little more indirect than above, and the two actions are not literally changing the same thing back to back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  React and React-Redux will batch those dispatches together because they're all occurring in the same event handler and the same event loop tick.  So, that will intentionally only result in a single re-render, using the final state.

If you change the handler to run after a timeout, React 17 does *not* automatically batch those updates together.  However, React 18 *will* batch them.  You can get similar behavior with React 17 by wrapping both dispatches in the [`batch()` API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) exported from React-Redux